# Laravel 5.0 auth not working without reason

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have this code to do an authentification login on my project

[image: Contract]

model :

[image: Contract]

I followed all the steps and it's supposed to authenticate me but it doesn`t work. Do you know what to do ?

Comment: have you create your own Authentication privider? How does the authentication guard know that souldd be using `usuario` and `password` as columns to compare?

Comment: @manix Please edit questions with care, you've just left two identical images after your edit. @ JesusVega please include code instead of images in your question.

Comment: @JesusVega When saving passwords for users did you hash them using `bcrypt()`?

Comment: @Bogdan, thank you. I have fixed it.

Comment: yeah the problem is that the password must be encrypted for eloquent can make the auth::attempt , also is better rename the column "contraseña" to password.

Answer (score 0):

yeah the problem is that the password must be encrypted for eloquent can make the auth::attempt , also is better rename the column "contraseña" to password